# switchin scenes on javafx

Tags: java, javafx

i have this code, i'd like when i click btn1, the scene of primaryStage must be  switchedfrom scene1 to scene2, 
i'm followign tuto, it works on the video, but not with me
here the code (not that system.ou.println in setOnAction works)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class SwitchingScenes4 extends Application{

    Stage window;
    Scene scene1 ,scene2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;

    Label label = new Label("Welcome to scene 1");
    Button btn = new Button("Go to Scene2");
    btn.setOnAction(e ->{
        window.setScene(scene2);
        System.out.println("ee");
    });

    VBox layout1 = new VBox(20);
    layout1.getChildren().addAll(label, btn);
    scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 200, 200);

    //btn2
    Button btn2 = new Button("Go to Scene1");
    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
        //primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        System.out.println("ff");       
    });

    StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
    layout2.getChildren().add(btn2);
    scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 200, 200);

    //Launching
    window.setTitle("Scenes");
    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.show();          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused the button that attaches the transition event processing to Scene 1

```
//btn2
Button btn2 = new Button("Go to Scene1");
btn2.setOnAction(e -> {
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    System.out.println("ff");
});
```